# Looking for a BASIC interpreter implemented in PHP

Tags: php, interpreter

Does anyone know of a PHP program that will interpret BASIC code? I have seen a [LOLCODE implementation](http://www.tetraboy.com/lolcode/) that looks like it's a good place to start, but if anyone has already developed something like that, i'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Can't find one in PHP but there is one in Javascript: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=92. If you scroll down that page, the author put a lot of efforts in explaining on how the thing works, which IMO is a good place to start.

Comment: well, even if it's not what i'm looking for, it's pretty cool :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually exactly what I wrote some months ago:

http://pub.32kb.org/files/entry/pBasic/pBasic.zip

It is a port of the one file BASIC implementation in JAVA called jASIC to be found here:

http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2010/07/18/jasic-a-complete-interpreter-in-one-java-file

Usage is like this:

```
$pbas = new pBasic();
$basicScript = file_get_contents('test.bas');
// execute
$pbas->interpret($basicScript);
```

And this is a sample BASIC script I use for a game concept of mine:

```
' list all the files on the current server, by memmaker

println ""                                      ' used to produce a blank line in the        output, the "" is needed for the parser

if "bin" = arg1 then getbinaries                ' determine which directory to show

print "Listing of / on " + _ENV_CONNECTED_SERVER
allfiles = list_files()                         ' get list of files from the system

goto init

getbinaries:

print "Listing of /bin on " + _ENV_CONNECTED_SERVER
allfiles = list_files(1)                        ' get list of bin files from the system

init:

filecount = count(allfiles)                     ' get the length of the array

counter = 0                                     ' init the counter for the loop

println " - " + filecount + " files found"      ' print the file count, note the "" prefix is needed because pBasic infers the type from the left argument of a binary operator

println ""

beginloop:

println get_element(allfiles, counter)          ' output the current filename

counter = counter + 1                           ' increment the loop counter

if counter < filecount then beginloop           ' break the loop when all files are output
```

As you can see, I expanded upon the original jASIC interpreter and added function calls and some other small changes.

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm afraid I couldn't get it to work. Any pointers?

Comment: Sure, I've added basic usage instructions above. Feel free to contact me for further questions.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I can't seem to get it to work :(