# Compilers and Interpreters written in php or compile to php

Tags: php, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm interesting in using other language where the server only accept php. So my question is:
What interpreters and compilers was written in php or compilers that compile to php?

So far I found:

- [JavaScript interpreter](http://include-once.org/p/phpjs/)
- [BASIC interpreter implemented in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084705/looking-for-a-basic-interpreter-implemented-in-php#answer-15969285)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is list of all languages written in other languages: http://web.archive.org/web/20130624094623/http://langlangmatrix.com